# Wordpress custom post type thumbnail size does not resize as I want

Tags: wordpress, thumbnails, custom-post-type

I created a custom post type 'film" and I want to resize it thumbnails to 100x125 px. I uploaded the images in these dimensions, but when I load the page, several images are showed to 86x125.

This is my functions.php

```
add_theme_support('post-thumbnails';
set_post_thumbnail_size(150, 150, true);
add_image_size('films-thumbnail', 100, 125, true);
```

And in my archive-films.php I wrote:

```
the_post_thumbnail('films-thumbnail');
```

But I say doesnt work for all images, I dont know if its for wordpress error or for markup error.

This is the list. http://goo.gl/Y3LFCq

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What size were the images you uploaded?

Comment: The last of them have risen to the 100x125, but the oldest were 116x150, but now I have a test, changing the size of one of the old and making it to 100x125 up with the same name in the same folder as old and still showing themselves to 86x125. As this http://goo.gl/xvH7j3

Comment: Ok, the problem is with the oldest images, I re-select the thumbnail image and this scale ok, thanks ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Download and install [Force Regenerate Thumbnails](http://wordpress.org/plugins/force-regenerate-thumbnails/). This properly resize all your thumbnails to the sizes set. It will also delete sizes that is not used in the theme. Another option is to download and install [Regenerate Thumbnails](http://wordpress.org/plugins/regenerate-thumbnails/). It does exactly the same, but does not delete image sizes that are unneccesary